# How do I get the file name from nodejs app.post?

Tags: node.js, multer

I want to get the file original name from this app.post (used with multer):

```
app.post('/', upload.array('file'), function(req, res){
    console.log(req.files);

    res.status(204).end();
});
```

Using `console.log(req.files)` I get:

```
[ { fieldname: 'file',
    originalname: 'TSy16rd913.jpg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    destination: './public/uploads/',
    filename: 'TSy16rd913.jpg',
    path: 'public/uploads/TSy16rd913.jpg',
    size: 110736 } ]
```

Using `console.log(req.files.originalname)` or `console.log(req.files.filename)` gives `undefined`.
So how do I get originalname or filename?

Comment: req.files is an array!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Roland Starke answer, `req.files` is an array, so you have to do something like this 
`req.files[0].filename`

To get all filenames :

```
req.files.forEach(function(value, key) {
  console.log(value.filename)
})
```